# Scalling in Magic Info Server for web url

Tags: zooming

I am using MagicInfo server and trying to display web url through Content section on Device which is TV screen. I managed to do it but page size is to big and it's not fit to screen. It seems that around 80% of zoom would be perfect fit but I am not able to find anywhere such settings.

Steps which I did

1. Created Content based on Web Url in Content section
2. Added device in Device section
3. Put content to device in Schedule section
   It works but as above - display is not fit to screen, there is no full page visibility. Expectation is to adjust scalling for content to have full page visibility (around 80% zoom should be fine)